# PHP mail() function does not deliver e-mails to MobileMe

Tags: php, mobileme

I'm having trouble sending e-mails using PHP's mail function when I'm sending them to MobileMe mail (@me.com). It works great for every other mail address I've tried. The e-mails just never arrive.

Answer (score 1):

mail() uses the system's configured mail facility. To see what's going on (probably SPAM filtering on Mobile Me's side), you'd have to check the system log files (that depends on the installed mail solution, but it's somewhere in /var/log).

If the local machine is configured to use a smarthost, you'd have to check the log file there.

If you don't have access to the log files, try executing `sendmail -t` and typing the whole email there as you would send it via PHP. You might get some more error information that way.